# How do I use "this" in a member function?

Tags: c++

I've written a member function of class Node to read a tree of Nodes in postfix order.

It will be called by the Node instance which is the root node of the tree.

So: N.postfix();

these appear to be illeagal:

```
*this->left.postfix();
*this->right.postfix();
```

What is the proper way to do this?

```
class Node
{
public:
    const char *cargo; 
    int depth; 
    Node *left; 
    Node *right

void Node::postfix()
{
    if (this==__nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        *this->left.postfix();
        *this->right.postfix();
        out<<*this->cargo<<"\n";
        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why silently return if `this==__nullptr`?  Your program has some pretty serious problems if that's ever true

Comment: No, after I implemented the answers I got, it works fine. The recursion (left) procedes until the leaf node is arrived at, then the node is __nullptr, and the next (right) recursive statement is executed.

Comment: @Peter - although this might, in most cases, work you are actually doing something very bad.  Calling a member function on a null pointer is UB.  It happens to work in this particular case because most implementations work such that it's something like "postfix(Node*n)" and comparing n==0 would not do anything bad.  It doesn't have to work though and may fail sometimes.

Comment: I would caution against using this==__nullptr. Calling member functions of null pointers results in undefined behavior from the C++ spec. I would use 
    if (left != __nullptr) {
        left->postfix();
    }
instead

Comment: Instead of out<<*this->cargo<<"\n"; use out<<*this->cargo<<std::endl;

Comment: To echo what @Noah says, you need to check whether `left` and `right` point to valid objects before calling member functions on them.   Calling the member function and then testing whether `this` is null is backwards and incorrect; it never works correctly, though it can appear to work correctly.

Comment: To add a further point, the Undefined Behaviour can be observed by making the `postfix()` function `virutal`: `virtual void Node::postfix() { ... }` Most implementations will throw a segmentation fault of some sort when a call is made to a virtual function through a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on calling a member function on a null pointer. I think I'll make this a non-member function.

Comment: You don't have to make it a non-member function - just use Akusete's suggestion, and check the pointers are not null before calling their members.

Comment: @AshleysBrain, Akusete: yes! thanks very much. I now have a four line function. Now I'm going to optimize the evaluation. I'll ask a separate question on that. Thanks to all for the great help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a member function, you don't generally need to use `this` to access class members; you can simply use:

```
left->postfix();
```

etc.

If you have function parameters or other local variables that have the same name as a class member variable, you can use `this` to refer to the member variable, e.g.,

```
this->left->postfix();
```

The reason that your code is illegal is that it does not correctly treat `left` as a pointer.  You need to dereference `left` using `->` in order to access its members, as shown in the correct code here.  (You could also use the equivalent `(*left).postfix()`, but that just makes you use more parentheses for no real benefit.)

The use of the indirection operator `*` at the start of the expression is also incorrect, because it is applied to the result of `postfix()` (i.e., it dereferences whatever is returned by `postfix()`).  `postfix()` doesn't return anything, so it's an error.  It is important to remember that the `.` and `->` operators both have higher precedence than `*`.

Answer (score 6):

The `->` operator dereferences a pointer, so the extra `*` will cause problems.  You can either do this:

```
this->left->postfix();
```

Or this:

```
(*this).left->postfix();
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit... I wasn't playing close enough attention.

Answer (score 1):

```
*this->left.postfix();
```

"Dereference the return value of calling postfix() on the 'left' member variable of this."

```
this->left->postfix();
//or
(*this->left).postfix();
```

"Call postfix() on the dereferenced 'left' member variable of this."